# pip install mysql-connector-python-8.0.30 installed completely - no errors. What are confer for settings .py [DATABASES ]

Tags: python, django, macos

**Thank You** - Your suggestion:Thank you.  **Your suggestions.**  DATABASES = {'default':{
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',                                                       'NAME': 'KMSFront',
'USER': 'root', 'PASSWORD': 'PWPWL', 'HOST': '127.0.0.1' 'PORT': 3306, 'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True  }}}.  **Error Message:**  "raise ImproperlyConfigured(django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check above exception. Use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:  'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'"
**Updated**
**Environment** = macOS Monterey V12.5 M1Max with Visual Studio Code + Python 3.10.6 + Django 4.1 + PIP3.  Have successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.30.  Current dbsqlite3 has populated tables.  When I run python manage.py migrate from dbsqlite3 to MySQL Community 8.0.30 the error messages include "Did you install mysqlclient."  Oracle documentation indicates the mysql-connector-python should be used and is all that is needed. Current DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': 'DatabaseName',    (These are the same settings in MySQL Workbench and mySQL that is running in shared mode)
'HOST': '127.0.0.1:3306',
'USER': 'root',
'PASSWORD': 'DDDDDD',

**Question:**  Are there separate configuration settings [options] to remove mysqlclient and replace it with mysql-connector-python-8.0.30?

Comment: Can you share the configurations, it looks like you have not configured it well.

Answer (score 0):

Your database settings should be to use oracle's connector-python:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'DatabaseName',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'DDDDDD',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I used your suggestions..  ATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'KMSFront',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'PWPWPWPWL',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
        }
        
     }
}.